# Java grades exercise

Tags: java

I'm Adrian and i'm kinda new to programming, would like to learn more and improve. I was asked to do a grade average exercise and i did this , but i'm stuck at making the code so if you type a number instead of a name the code will return from the last mistake the writer did , like it asks for a name and you put "5". In my code gives an error and have to re-run it. Any tips?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.io.*;

class Grades {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int j = 1;
    double sum = 0;
    double average;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert Student's Name");
    String name = keyboard.next();

    System.out.println("Insert Student's Surname");
    String surname = keyboard.next();

    System.out.println("Student's name: " + name + " " + surname);

    System.out.println("How many Grades?");
    int nVotes = keyboard.nextInt();
    int[] arrayVotes = new int[nVotes];

    System.out.println("Now insert all the grades");

    for (int i=0; i<arrayVotes.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Insert the grade " + j);
      arrayVotes[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
      j++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<arrayVotes.length; i++) {
      sum += arrayVotes[i];
    }

    average = sum / arrayVotes.length;
    System.out.println("Student's grade average is: " + average);

    System.out.println("Does he have a good behaviour? Answer with true or false");
    boolean behaviourStudent = keyboard.nextBoolean();

    average = !behaviourStudent ? Math.floor(average) : Math.ceil(average);

    System.out.println("The grade now is: " + average);

    keyboard.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Press [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59704897/edit) and change it.

Comment: if you want to track changes, you can achieve that with a list

Comment: *in my code gives an error* please share the error message

Answer (score 0):

At the heart of any solution for this, it requires a loop, and a condition for resetting.

```
String result = null;
while (result == null) {
    //OUT: Prompt for input
    String input = keyboard.next();
    if (/* input is valid */) {
        result = input; //the loop can now end
    } else {
        //OUT: state the input was invalid somehow
    }
    //Since this is a loop, it repeats back at the start of the while
}
//When we reach here, result will be a non-null, valid value
```

I've left determining whether a given input is valid up to your discretions. That said, you may consider learning about methods next, as you can abstract this prompting/verification into a much simpler line of code in doing so (see: the DRY principle)

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to do it.
But the best way is to use regex to validate the user input.
Have a look at the below code, you can add other validations as well using regex.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    class Grades {

        public static boolean isAlphabetOnly(String str) 
        { 
            return (str.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")); 
        }   

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int j = 1;
        double sum = 0;
        double average;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert Student's Name");
        String name = keyboard.next();
        if(!isAlphabetOnly(name)){
            System.out.println("Please enter alfabets only");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Insert Student's Surname");
        String surname = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Student's name: " + name + " " + surname);

        System.out.println("How many Grades?");
        int nVotes = keyboard.nextInt();
        int[] arrayVotes = new int[nVotes];

        System.out.println("Now insert all the grades");

        for (int i=0; i<arrayVotes.length; i++) {
          System.out.println("Insert the grade " + j);
          arrayVotes[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
          j++;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<arrayVotes.length; i++) {
          sum += arrayVotes[i];
        }

        average = sum / arrayVotes.length;
        System.out.println("Student's grade average is: " + average);

        System.out.println("Does he have a good behaviour? Answer with true or false");
        boolean behaviourStudent = keyboard.nextBoolean();

        average = !behaviourStudent ? Math.floor(average) : Math.ceil(average);

        System.out.println("The grade now is: " + average);

        keyboard.close();
      }
    }
```